# Images (*.jpg, *.png, ...) correctly displayed on my localhost but missing in Gitlab CI and pre-production environment

Tags: gitlab, png, jpeg, gitlab-ci

I have this issue, I don't understand what is wrong in my code.

```
<div>
    <div class="img_1"></div>
</div>
```

and in css :

```
.img_1 {
  background-image: url(../../content/images/appmobile_b.jpg);
  background-size: 305px 507px;
  width: 305px;
  height: 507px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 398px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

I can display images locally, then they are missing after deploying on a gitlab CI.
I've tried changing the path, add width in html, change extensions.. but nothing worked.

When I am on gitlab, I can display the images from their folder... but nothing in my pre-production environement.
It looks silly stuff... But it drives me crazy.
Do you have an idea, or what I am doing wrong... ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check out if the images are in their folder on the pre-production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a folder which contains all my *.jpg or *.png files in Gitlab. And I can display them within GitLab, by clicking on them. They look not damaged.
[Folder in gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M6W8.jpg)
I've tried to put an SVG for an instagram icon, so it worked. But still the other images (and other icons, which are a *.jpg files) not showing up.